# Matrix transformation for eigenvalue problem and HPC

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue

I have matrix Q

`Q.shape` is `(2,2,n,n)`. Where `n` is `k**2` , k > 1

So Q is block matrix:

`Q[0,0].shape` is `(n,n)`

`Q[0,1].shape` is `(n,n)`

`Q[1,0].shape` is `(n,n)`

`Q[1,1].shape` is `(n,n)`

Nested inside Q matrices are sparsed.

I have eigenvalue problem Q * v = lambda * v.
Where `v.shape` is vector of vectors `(2,1,n,1)`

Matrices are sparsed because they are extremely huge. (k suppose to be bigger then 1000).
The only solution I see for the moment it's to use `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs`, but Q should be square.

What if I use `scipy.sparse.hstack` and `scipy.sparse.vstack` to transform Q shape `(2,2,n,n)` to `Qs` `(2n,2n)` and v vector shape will be `vs` `(2n,1)`?

**1. Will eigenvalue problem be legit with: Qs * vs = lambda * vs?**

If yes, in this case I can use this:
`w, v = scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs(Qs, k=1, sigma=1.4, which='SM')`

**2. As well I looking for eigenvalue solvers that could be faster then `eigs` from `scipy.sparse.linalg` for extremely large matrix `Qs`
What can you advice for hpc slurm based with gpu?**

There is Intel python, it's the only one speed up that I found.

There is CUDA sparse library *cuSOLVER* seems to be good. But I did't find examples for slurm.

Hope I describe it understandable.
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4020194/matrix-transformation-for-eigenvalue-problem) is as well my first question with a rendered matrices.